# Why Does Sequelize.js in Node.js always return true from a MySQL bit field?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a Node.Js Express application and I'm using the Sequelize.js OR/M to query a MySQL 5.6 database. I have a table called homes that contains a couple of bit fields (one of which is called isrental which I have defined as Boolean in the model. When querying the db, these fields always return true even when I have a 0 stored on the record. Here's a quick code example:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize-mysql').sequelize;
var orm = new Sequelize('mysql://procHOAPro:password@NewMasterBedRm/HOAPro'), {
    dialect: 'mysql',
    language: 'en'
});
var Home = orm.define('homes', {
    homeid : Sequelize.INTEGER,
    state : Sequelize.STRING,
    county : Sequelize.STRING,
    city : Sequelize.STRING,
    zip : DataTypes.STRING,
    isrental : {type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: true, defaultValue: false},
    isbuilderowned : {type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: true, defaultValue: false},
    mailingaddress : Sequelize.STRING
});    
Home.all().success(function(homes) {
    console.log(homes[0].isrental);
    console.log(homes[1].isrental);
});
```

table definition:

`CREATE TABLE 'homes' (
  'homeid' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'state' varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  'county' varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  'city' varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  'zip' varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  'section' varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  'township' int(11) NOT NULL,
  'townshipdir' varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  'range' int(11) NOT NULL,
  'rangedir' varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  'block' int(11) NOT NULL,
  'lot' int(11) NOT NULL,
  'physicaladdress' varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  'isrental' bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  'isbuilderowned' int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  'mailingaddress' varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('homeid'),
  UNIQUE KEY 'homeid_UNIQUE' ('homeid')
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

output:

> Executing: SELECT * FROM `homes`;
>   true <--this is bs...it's a 0 in the db
>   true <--this is bs...it's a 0 in the db

As an fyi, I also used the node-orm OR/M and I got the exact same behavior.

Comment: I am not familiar with the package in question, so I am not putting this as a definite answer. But why are you mapping a bit field to a Boolean attribute in the model? Shouldn't the field also be Boolean? Or try mapping it to a bit (if the ORM supports that type).

Comment: I am mapping it to a Boolean in the model while the DB equivalent is a BIT. This is the common mapping in most OR/Ms in that a bit field on a table maps to a Boolean on the resulting object. The DB doesn't have a Boolean field type and conversely the OR/M doesn't have a bit type.

Comment: Sequelize defines `BOOLEAN` as [`TINYINT(1)`](http://sequelizejs.com/documentation#models-data-types) or bit. That part is fine.

Comment: Can you post the table description too? Your columns might be out of order or something hinky causing sequelize to mess up.

Comment: Added table definition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your table definitions seem correct, the error is with sequelize / the way sequelize and node-mysql plays together. Node-mysql returns the bit field as a Buffer instance, but sequelize expects a tinyint. The tinyint can be converted to boolean by double negating it (`!!value`), whereas double negating a buffer always returns true.

The fix seems pretty easy, just check if the value is a buffer, before trying to convert it to boolean. Could you please create an issue for it on the sequelize github, then I'll hopefully get around to fixing it soon